# How to change tailwind.config directory, when using Nuxt UI?

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, config, nuxtjs3

Nuxt UI does not allow to add @nuxtjs/tailwindcss to modules, as it already contains it.
How can I change the directory of tailwindcss.config file, when using Nuxt UI?